# Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ not contained in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ not contained in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

---

completely stuck on it. can I get some help please.

Answer (score 13):

$K$ must contain $1$, thus also $\mathbb{N}$ by addition, and every $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ by taking the inverse.

So $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $K$.

$K$ contains a complex(non-real) number $x$, so it contains $\mathbb{Q}+x\mathbb{Q}$, which is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Proof of density: let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. ($1$,$x$) is a base of $\mathbb{C}$ seen as a real vector space, so $z=a+bx$ with $a$ and $b$ real numbers. $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you have $a_n$ and $b_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ which converge toward $a$ and $b$ respectively.
So $a_n+b_n x$ lives in $\mathbb{Q}+x\mathbb{Q}$ and converges toward $z$.

Comment: Alternatively $K$ is a field of characteristics zero, so $\Bbb Q\subseteq K$.

Comment: @Asaf How do you know $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K$, if not through the reasoning justt gives?

Comment: @Martian: True. Luckily, as intelligent human beings we can "remember" things like "Oh, $K$ is a field, so it must contain a prime field, in this case $\Bbb Q$". We don't have to repeat every proof of every argument every time we use it.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: Show that the (topological!) closure of $K$ is a subfield $L$ of $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $K$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, $L$ contains $\mathbb{R}$, the topological closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}] = 2$ and $L$ is assumed to contain an element of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, we must have $L = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That's nice!${}$

Answer (score 3):

Since $K$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$, there's some $z \in K - \mathbb{R}$. Thus $1$ and $z$ form a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Now, show that if you take any basis of $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and consider the subspace of $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, then this subspace will be dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. If $K$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb R$ then it contains some element $x\notin\Bbb R$ such that $x^2\in\Bbb R$. Show that $K$ contains something which looks a bit like $\Bbb Q[i]$.

Comment: still confused. just explain more elaborately please.thanks for your time.

Comment: Every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ contains some $x$ such that $x^2 \in \mathbb{R}$, for instance $x = 0$. You must have meant something else.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear verbal critique on the answer, in addition to the refreshing downvote!

Comment: Fair enough! I can't see why $K$ contains an $x\notin\mathbb R$ such that $x^2\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @user26857: As for the mathematical question, because $\Bbb C$ has degree $2$ over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If $K=\mathbb Q(\pi+i)$, then there is no $x\in K-\mathbb R$ such that $x^2\in\mathbb R$.